# Point local Gradle module to local Maven module

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, gradle

I have 3 modules on my Intellij:

- A Maven module called M1
- A Gradle module called G1
- A Maven module called M2

M1 and G1 are both dependent on M2 and this is declared in M1's pom.xml and G1's build.gradle with all being the same version as what is defined on M2.

I then import a class belonging to M2 on both M1 and G1. When I `Right Click -> Go To -> Implementation(s)` on this class I get different results.

M1 works as expected and opens up the source code on my local M2 module. G1 on the other hand decompiles the class and shows me the decompiled version even though the actual module and its source code is present as a local module in Intellij.

How do I make Gradle dependencies on a Maven module work exactly the same as Maven to Maven dependencies do?

Comment: Can you show how you are declaring your dependency (in both M1 and G1) ?

Comment: Maybe you can do [`downloadSources=true`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html#org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule:downloadSources) ?